# Choosing a suitable PFD for PLL

Tags: digital-logic, pll, detector

I'm building a capacitive vibration sensor and it has to reject the stray capacitance by locking the LC oscillator at 64 MHz, where I can demodulate relatively small frequency changes. The best way to do it seems to be a PLL and I chose to lock it to an 8 MHz crystal reference (see diagram below).

[image]

However, I stumbled upon a variety of PFDs and I don't understand which one I should use; which one is better for my application. I've found these 3 topologies but I don't understand the difference between them, which one will give me better noise, spurious performance etc:

[image][image]

[image]

I also found this detector ([source](http://www.cppsim.org/Publications/JNL/perrott_jssc10.pdf)), it has higher gain, so I should get lower noise with it but they use it in conjunction with a frequency detector, so I'm not sure about it. However, if they are using the detector only for decreasing lock time, it's fine since the lock time is not a problem in my case.

[image]

Comment: in which context/for which application do you need that 64 MHz? I'd probably just buy a 2€ ARM microcontroller with a built-in PLL for its internal clocks and just configure one pin to expose that internal clock, done, next. But: if this is for sensitive analog applications, that might not fly, because jitter. But you mention none of your requirements (aside from frequency), so we can't help you pick the best architecture.

Comment: @MarcusMüller it's a capacitive vibration sensor and it has to reject the stray capacitance by locking the oscillator at 64 MHz, where I can demodulate relatively small frequency changes. Guess I should edit the question

Comment: so, frequency stability over an average > 16 periods is relevant, small oscillator phase irregularities not so much?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes, correct

Comment: then definitely consider just using e.g. a Microchip SAMD10 or an ST STM32F0 or something similarly cheap and their internal clocking including built-in PLLs and VCOs.

Comment: @MarcusMüller it looks like I need to clarify this even more. I can't use an internal VCO because I'm using an external VCO where the capacitive sensor is connected in parallel with varactors. I'll add a block diagram to a question.

Comment: *I've found these 3 topologies but I don't understand the difference between them* The (dis)advantages of each topology might be listed there where you found the design. Also there is plenty of study material about PLLs and phase detectors. I suggest you study those.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie so what books can you suggest? I found only one book that more or less covers the phase frequency detectors: Rohde - Digital PLL frequency synthesizers. The rest of the books only covered a XOR and 2 DFF + NAND detectors.

Comment: @Archimedes what's the bandwidth of your system? Both 8 MHz and 64 MHz would be relatively simple to digitize directly and do the frequency detection completely in software, which comes with a lot of advantages

Comment: @MarcusMüller the oscillator may drift between 56..84 MHz and the maximum deviation from the signal of interest is ±400 kHz. I kind of already doing the demodulation in "digital", using a sigma-delta detector (2 DFFs + XOR) and then low passing the output since I need an analog output.

Comment: @Archimedes ah, ok. So, by the way, regarding your different topologies: I think the first and the second picture are essentially identical?

Comment: Do you need a PFD, or will a PD do? Start with the simplest, an XOR gate, and get more complicated if you find that won't work. If you tell us why it won't work (capture range, lock range, lock time, noise floor ...) we can better advise you what to try next.

Comment: @MarcusMüller looks like you're right. I thought there might be some difference between NAND and NOR versions but looks like they're identical.

Comment: @Neil_UK I've never seen PDs being used for frequency multiplication. Besides, my budget and time are heavily limited, so there's little room for experimentation, it would be better for me to get some understanding of things than just getting practical experience.

Comment: It appears that you do not understand PLLs very well, nor do you have a good grasp of your own requirements. I can't decide whether to put this on hold as "too broad" or "unclear". We just don't have a clear enough picture of your level of skill, or of the system design in order to be able to give you a specific, concise answer. One obvious question: You already have an "FM demodulator" -- why can't you use feedback from there to stabilize your oscillator, rather than adding a separate PLL?

Comment: @DaveTweed yes, I'm new to PLLs but my requirements are clear enough, I just don't know what information I should provide to make it clear to others.

Comment: @MarcusMüller asked you what the bandwidth of your system is. To clarify, what is the range of vibration frequencies that you're trying to measure?

Comment: @DaveTweed the vibration frequencies are 100-15000 Hz. Also I don't think that feedback from the demodulator will work since sigma-delta demodulators have a characteristic that looks like a zigzag and it will just lock the oscillator to the nearest linear region, compromising amplitude measurement accuracy since ΔF/ΔC is not constant in the oscillator full frequency range.

Comment: I mean, I can make two frequency comparators that will restrict the demodulator from going into the wrong region but still to achieve locking I'll need an opamp based PI controller that will increase noise and complexity, won't I?

Comment: You've no measurement on your varactor drive voltage, so it seems the PLL loop BW must be well below 100Hz if you're going to measure all of the variation on the demodulation of the output frequency. Is the FM demodulator DC or AC coupled, that is, does it give you absolute frequency output or just changes? I don't think I've see a demod described as sigma delta before, do you have a link to it? XORs aren't just for frequency multiplication, they also make the quietest, simplest phase detectors, though capture range depends on the loop bandwidth, so often need additional capture complication.

Comment: @Neil_UK here. I can give more details if you want, quite interesting stuff actually. Allows you to directly (w/o IF stages) demodulate virtually any frequency with a low-frequency reference clock. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3702179_A_narrow-band_delta-sigma_frequency-to-digital_converter

What regards the XOR, my goal right now is to reduce noise. Initially I had an FLL with its architecture described in my previous comment and I'm now trying to optimize noise in the first place. I know that XOR is the quietest detector but that PI controller really ruins the noise performance

Comment: So I opted for charge pump based PLL instead of frequency detector based FLL because they don't require any active circuitry to lock to a given frequency. Besides, from what I've read in the 4046 app note, a XOR detector doesn't cover whole VCO range (without active loop filter at least) and I need a reliable lock.

Comment: The demodulator gives DC output (low-pass filtered digital output) with peaks and zeros at each half of the sampling clock (god, I hope it makes sense), so you can't measure frequency with it, only its position relative to a current "harmonic" of the sampling clock.

Comment: @Archimedes As you appear to like interesting stuff, there is a true wideband sigma delta fast frequency counter published, rather than the narrowband one you linked, that would be capable of counting your oscillator in one go, with a bandwidth wide enough to demodulate 15kHz audio, and with a true frequency readout, and arbitrary sigma delta order, rather than just the first with no clue as to how to extend it as in your link. Have a look at US patent 4984254. Figure 4 seems the best fit for your application. Choose lowest ref clock that meets audio bandwidth, maybe 1-10MHz region?

Comment: @Neil_UK thanks, I'll definitely try it! And you actually used XOR as a phase detector, right?

Comment: @Archimedes There's a lot of technology (aka knowhow) to making a good PLL, and it's oh so easy to make a bad one, whatever basic components you use. Yes, I've used a 74AC86 as the PSD in a very low noise fractional N PLL, where the classic 3-state 'two d-flops and a gate' doesn't work at all well (the latter only works for integer N synthesis, it's too non-linear for delta sigma). If you build US4984254, take care with the PSD, if non-linear it can mix the shaped noise down to baseband.